# Deleting style categories in QGIS3 leads to incorrect feature count

Tags: pyqgis, style, pyqgis-3, categorized-renderer

If I use PyQGIS to delete style categories of a layer the feature count gets messed up:

Before deleting the category (style class) "3x20/15mm /VL" the featurecount shows 1 feature which is correct:

[image]

After deleting the 2nd category the featurecount of the class "3x20/15mm /VL" is incorrect:

[image]

I use following PyQGIS to delete the category:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
r = layer.renderer()
layerCategories = r.categories()
print(layerCategories)
r.deleteCategory(1)
#del layerCategories[0]
if r is not None:
    layer.setRenderer(r)
layer.dataProvider().forceReload()
if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
    layer.triggerRepaint()
else:
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
mView = iface.layerTreeView()
mView.refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Some test data can be found here: https://gist.github.com/thbaumann/5af83e18ba2de95fb0f65256a85e2417

Is this a QGIS3 bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A clue indicating it's a bug in my opinion `model = mView.layerTreeModel();print([i.data(0) for i in model.children()])` The underlying model to the view does not refresh. FYI, I've also seen that If you save and reopen the project after your PyQGIS operations, the legend is refreshing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seems a bug in my opinion (see my comment), you can bypass it using the following (tested)

```py
layer.setRenderer(layer.renderer().clone())
```